# Moshi: When is Reflection needed?

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi, reflections, kotlin-reflect

Currently using Moshi with Retrofit but need to look back as I noticed I am not implementing it right and confused when to add `kotlin-reflect` in the dependencies.

According to README

> The reflection adapter requires the following additional dependency:

```
implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.13.0")
```

I thought the above dependency is the actual Moshi dependency but it seems it is not needed unless you are using `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory`. What is `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` anyway, is it responsible for converting Kotlin classes to JSON?

Currently I have this dependencies and annotation processor.

```
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    // Retrofit 2 + Moshi
    ksp 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
```

If I will be using Moshi with Codegen only, can I remove the others and ended up on just these two dependency?

```
    ksp 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'
```